# Woocommerce purchase note?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I think i am missing something glaringly obvious here: 
I am trying to include the pruchase note in the `customer-completed-order.php` so the customer receives the note along with the purchase confirmation, but I am failing miserably.

Here is what I tried:

```
<?php echo '<div class=\"product-purchase-note\">'.  $purchase_note .  'PURCHASE NOTE</div>'; ?>
```

and this

```
<?php       
   $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note');
  echo '<div class="product-purchase-note">' .  $purchase_note . '</div>';
?>
```

and this:

```
<?php       
   $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true)) :
    echo '<td class="product-purchase-note">' . apply_filters('the_content', $purchase_note) . '</td>';
?>
```

and this:

```
<?php 

  if ($order->status=='completed' || $order->status=='processing') {
    if ($purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true))
     echo '<div class="product-purchase-note"><div>' . apply_filters('the_content', $purchase_note) . '</div></div>';
} ?>
```

Nothing seems to work.

It shows up on the order-received page but will not show on the order confirmed email.
Any help is much appreciated I am also open to some other method to get the note to the client upon purchase, such as custom meta values maybe?

Comment: Same problem, missing we purchase-note (german Kauf-Notiz). Found any solution?

Comment: I did find a solution yews I can't remeber what is was now give me a min I'll see if i can give it

Comment: you need to set this to plane text : https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php

Comment: which exactly? and why set to plain text? What does plain text mean here?

Comment: Plain text means it doesn not send it out in html

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but, use `$order->customer_note` instead of `$purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note');`

Comment: I'd be happy to except this answer but it's not quite right you need to set it to plain text to make this work for some reason..

Comment: curiously this didn't worked for me. maybe they fixed it in a later version

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because `$_product` hasn't been set yet in the `completed-customer-order.php` template.

In this case you need to pull out the products from the order yourself:

```
<?php
    $items = $order -> get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $order -> get_product_from_item( $item );
        // copied from woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php
        $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $product -> id, '_purchase_note', true );
        echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) );
    }
```

Comment: You should add the closing ?> php tag. This was the only answer that worked for me.